# Artifacts Between rating bar images

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-resources, ratingbar

I Created My custom Rating bar in android but I'm having some problems on devices with Lower lvl API's.
I successfully implemented it on a htc one x with ICS however on a htc desire with android 2.2 I have artifacts between the images.
I created png resources for every screen density.

Here is an image of htc desire with hdpi screen:
[image: htc desire with artifacts]

Here is an image of htc one x with xhdpi screen:
[image: htc one x without artifacts]

Following is included in my layout file:
    
Following is my drawable resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+android:id/background"
          android:drawable="@drawable/bone_empty" />
    <item android:id="@+android:id/progress"
          android:drawable="@drawable/bone_full" />
</layer-list>
```

And Following is my res/values-hdpi/styles.xml (used by htc desire)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="dogBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/dog_rating_bar</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">48dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">48dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And Following is my res/values-xhdpi/styles.xml (Used by htc one x)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="dogBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/dog_rating_bar</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">64dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">64dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```